# Merge two sub graphs in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have two subgraphs in the following way

```
                      (root1)                    (root2)
                       / | \                      / | \
                      /  |  \                    /  |  \
                     /   |   \                  /   |   \
                   (a1) (a2) (a3)             (b1) (b2) (b3)
```

I want to create a new graph by merging above two

```
                               (root)
                          /  /  /  \  \  \
                       (a1)(a2)(a3)(b1)(b2)(b3)
```

Is there a way to just replace one of the root nodes in one of the tree instead of iterating all the children of one tree, disconnect the current root, and connect to new root?

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario you will need to disconnect the relationships from one of the root nodes to be able to attach it to the other one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some unique property like "name" to identify the root nodes and only 1 hop (relation) between your root nodes and leaf nodes, this query should do the work.

```
match (rt2 {name:"root2"})--> (n), (rt1 {name:"root1"}) 
detach delete rt2 
create  (rt1)-[:RELATED_TO]->(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/#merge-nodes) to "merge" the nodes in a node-list into the first node in the list, which includes essentially "moving" all the relationships over to the first node. You should read about the powerful options that are available, to get the results you want.

Here is a very simple example. This query will merge `root2` into `root1` (overwriting all properties in `root1` having the same name as a property in `root2`), and essentially "move" all `root2` properties over to `root1`:

```
MATCH (root1), (root2)
WHERE root1.id = 123 AND root2.id = 234
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([root1, root2], {}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

You can specify options in the `{}` map to modify the above default behavior.